# What phrase pasted in vim's normal mode would create havoc in the text?

Tags: vim

If pasting a text in `vim` I forget to switch to insert mode and the text streams in normal mode, usually what happens is that the "command" is getting executed until the first insert-mode character (`i` `I` `a` `A` `o` `O` `s` `S` `c` `C`) and the rest text then gets pasted, leaving some degree of a mess.

Are there words (or code snippets) which would create a lot of mess if pasted in normal mode?

e.g. `use` would undo the last change and overwrite the undo history, which can cost some nerves.

I guess as an aside, maybe there is a way to work around that kind of human error?

Comment: "overwrite the undo history" - no such thing in Vim, since Vim has undo *tree*. All you need to do is `:earlier 30s`. Or use one of the nice plugins that lets you visualise the undo tree (undotree, gundo, vim-mundo...) There's no reason for nerves.

Comment: Thank you for the answers to the second question, the paste function works well in the insert mode. However I'm still interested in the dangers of *inadvertent* pasting into the normal mode.

Answer (score 2):

Type `:set paste` before pasting code, and `:set nopaste` after. See `:help paste` for more.

GUI versions of Vim, like MacVim or GVim, have much better OS integration than terminal Vim, and do not have problems like this.

Comment: paste is acting in insert mode only, and is great to keep the formatting, however it does not help in normal mode. GUI versions are handy, but very often inaccessible for me while working on embedded devices and/or over SSH

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with terminal vim, then `:set paste` will put vim in paste mode and allows you paste in verbatim. This will avoid unexpected effects. More details at `:help paste`.
Also, you might like to `:set nopaste` after the pasting.

If typing `:set paste/nopaste` now and then bothers you, then you might like to have(in your vimrc)

```
set pastetoggle=<F11>
source ~/.vimrc
```

Now pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>will toggle "paste/nopaste" option alternately.

Comment: thank you for the pastetoggle hint, I have solved the toggle with the following mapping: `noremap <S-F11> :set nonumber<CR>:set norelativenumber<CR>:set nopaste<CR>` and `noremap <C-F11> :set number!<CR>:set relativenumber!<CR>:set paste!<CR>` .
this way i can also e.g. copy without line numbers